# How do I kill the docker processes?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have tried

```
docker kill name_of_the_process
```

But the error is

```
 Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: name_of_the_container: Container name_of_the_container is not running
```

There are a lot of processes when I run `docker ps -a`, how do I kill those, they are stopped but not killed

Comment: docker ps -a |xargs docker kill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stopped container is killed. There is no running process, but there is a writable container specific filesystem and some metadata remaining which allows you to debug the stopped container and restart it. To remove that, use `docker container rm` (or the former alias `docker rm`) to remove the stopped container data. e.g.

```
docker container ls -aqf status=exited | xargs docker container rm
```

Answer (score 0):

`docker ps` Shows you the running containers. If you add the `-a` flag it will print out **all** the containers, even the ones **not** running.

You can not "stop" a non-running container, it is already stopped.

You can find more information here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

If you wish to remove the container, you can remove it by id or name. The command for that is `docker rm <id/name>`

Tip: You can use the first few chars of the id to identify the container, you don't need the whole id